# MVC3 - lightweight CMS that can be added to existing application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, content-management-system, integration

I'm trying to find a CMS that can be incorporated into an existing MVC3 app.

I've played with N2, and can't get the damn thing to work in VS2010 or with .NET 4.

Umbarco doesn't appear to support MVC yet

Orchard looks great, but wants to own the whole application.

DNN is just a mess.

Any other brilliant solutions?

**Post-mortem Dec 2011**

This is an old post, but I thought I'd share my experiences with Orchard, and why I decided to go a different direction.

**NHibernate**

Aside from the *very* large number of transactions per page (literally dozens in some cases), each and every query was executed using `sp_executesql`. While not quite as bad as using `Exec()`, this rubs me the wrong way. Currently, my database is locked down so that applications can only execute stored procedures - that is, they can't perform select/update/delete, list entities such as tables, get any metadata, etc. This is a requirement for tier-wise unit testing, compile-time verification of the database, security and encapsulation of database logic from the application code.

**Source Deployment**

Orchard requires that the entire source for your site (views, .cs source files, etc) is deployed to the production server. The sheer number of source files that need to deployed boggles the mind.

**Integration with an existing application**

The manner in which Orchard is structured effectively requires it to be the point of entry for the web application. This means that you're going to spend some time modifying and reimplementing your app to get it to play nice with Orchard.

**Conclusion**
There were quite a few other issues that I encountered, but those are the highlights. Individually, each of those could have been a deal breaker. Together, they removed Orchard as a viable solution.

I'm now evaluating [Telerik's Sitefinity](http://www.sitefinity.com/). It's not MVC, which saddens me, but:

2. The admin interface is extremely powerful. Aside from a master page and some stylesheets that I put together in VS, we've been able to handle all of the layout via Sitefinity's admin tools.
3. I mean, it's **really** powerful. You can use the admin interface to *edit the admin interface*. Think about that for a minute.
4. Widgets are implemented as ASP.NET user controls. Most of my existing controls just dropped right in with zero modifications.
5. Database access is handled via Telerik's OpenAccess ORM. While Sitefinity doesn't natively use stored procedures, OpenAccess fully supports using them for all operations. Also, according to Telerik, OpenAccess does not, in any way, rely on reflection, which provides significant performance benefits in heavy-load apps.
6. **There are several solutions available for using Razor markup within widgets**, which is one of the great benefits (to me) of using MVC. Also, I've been told that native Razor support is in active development.
7. [It's not free](http://www.sitefinity.com/purchase.aspx). In reality, however, a few grand barely breaks the noise floor in terms of development time.
8. Super crazy fast. Startup time is a bit on the slow side, but once it's running, it's very quick.
9. Built on top of Telerik's awesome, proven RAD controls.

Apologies for the long post. Hopefully this will be helpful.

Comment: THanks for sharing you experiences. I will consider your suggestions since I'm in a similar situation right now!

Comment: @hydr don't hesitate to contact their support guys. They have (and use) a direct line to the developers. We've been using it for about a year, and they're awesome. Also added MVC support in the latest release. (they do quarterly releases - blindingly fast.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find these projects useful.  You can probably model a simple CMS based on one of their projects.

- [MvcCms](http://www.mvccms.com/)
- [MvcMS](http://cmsmvc.codeplex.com/)
- [Atomic CMS](http://atomiccms.codeplex.com/)
- [Mytrip.mvc](http://mytripmvc.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive list. Wound up going with orchard; its surprisingly easy to bend to your will after you get used to it.

Comment: David, how did you end up integrating Orchard into your MVC app.

Comment: @Acoustic - You don't, you integrate your MVC app into Orchard.

Comment: @MystereMan Totally True..I gave up on Orchard after several attempts.Maybe I was missing something...Evaluating Umbraco 5 now.

Comment: For anyone visiting, Umbrack 5 was dropped and is no longer in prod.

Answer (score 1):

Try Web Noodles..The new CMS developed using mvc3. [WebNoodles](http://webnoodles.codeplex.com/).It is easy to integrate .But the thing is it is still in beta stage..But you must give it a try ...